# How to show short cut to android sdk and adt manager on eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have updated eclipse. But I have to always go to android sdk folder on my file system and navigate to tools located in that folder. In ealry versions, there were short cuts to adt and sdk tools on eclipse. They were shown under the menu bar of eclipse. Is there way to get them back again on to eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

First, these should show up automatically under the "Java" perspective in Eclipse. You can show it using `Window->Open Perspective->Java` (or if `Java` does not appear there, use `Other` and select `Java` from the list).

If you want to add it to other perspectives (like the `Java EE` perspective)

1. Choose `Window->Customize Perspective`
2. Click on the `Command Groups Availability` tab
3. Check `Android SDK and AVD Manager`
4. Press `Ok`

You may also want to check `Android Wizards` to get the buttons for creating an Android XML file.